# How can get value when finish a promise

Tags: javascript

I'm developing my first library in javascript.

Sorry if I don't explain myself well because my english level is not good and probably I'll do grammatical errors, so apologies.

My problem is that when I call initService function that I've created in my library return a promise, but I want that return the real value of service property. I've write logs inside that method and this is how show all logs.

> [library] calling...
>
> [html file] html calling... -> return a Promise
>
> [library] finished -> return value of service.

I knwo that in moment when I call initService from my html file is a Promise and later when promise has finished return the value.

How can do that when I call initService on my html file return the value of service and not a promise?

Here is my code in html file:

```
<html lang="en">
<head> 
   <script src="./js/library.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let service = window.APIServiceLibrary.initService('APIService');
        console.log('html calling... ', service);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my library:

```
(function(window) {
    // You can enable the strict mode commenting the following line
    // 'use strict';

    function APIServiceLibrary(){
        var _serviceLibraryObject = {};

        var props = {
            service: undefined,
            intervalID: undefined
        };

        _serviceLibraryObject.createService = function(name) {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                setInterval(() => {
                    props.service = this.getAPIService(name);
                    if (props.service !== undefined) {
                        this.stopService(props.intervalID);
                        resolve(props.service);
                    }
                }, 500);
            });
        };

        _serviceLibraryObject.getAPIService = function(name) {
            // window.APIService is a global value
            if (window[name] !== undefined) {
                return window[name];
            }
        };

        _serviceLibraryObject.stopService = function() {
            for (var i = 1; i < props.intervalID; i++) {
                window.clearInterval(i);
            }
        }

        _serviceLibraryObject.initService = async function(name){
            console.log('calling...');
            props.service = await this.createService(name);
            console.log('finished: ', props.service);
            return props.service;
        };

        return _serviceLibraryObject;
    }

    if(typeof(window.APIServiceLibrary) === 'undefined'){
        window.APIServiceLibrary = APIServiceLibrary();
    }

})(window);
```

EDITION:

html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.APIServiceLibrary.createService('APIService')
    .then(service => {
        // call functions that you need
        console.log('service: ', service);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('error: ', err);
    });
</script>
```

Remove from the library next method:

```
_serviceLibraryObject.initService = async function(name){
    console.log('calling...');
    props.service = await this.createService(name);
    console.log('finished: ', props.service);
};
```

Comment: Call `.then` on the Promise to consume it (or use `await`)

Comment: I know that I can use then but I would like get the value when finish the promise that is inside my library.

Comment: You can't. You have to wait for the asynchronous action to complete. You can't synchronously use a value that comes asynchronously until someone invents time travel

Comment: so bad for me :(   I edit the question